# Why Firestore DocumentSnapshot.exist() is always `false` addOnCompleteListener?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating basic application to retrieve user data from Firestore and if the user is new(in Firestore i.e. document should not exist) i am adding a welcome note(some default data to DB).

```
private fun createUserIfNeeded(user: FirebaseUser) {
    fireBaseFireStore.collection("Users").document(user.uid).get().addOnCompleteListener {
        if (it.isSuccessful && !it.result!!.exists()) {
            val defaultData = 
                hashMapOf("head" to "Hello", "body" to "Welcome to NoteIt...")

            fireBaseFireStore
                .collection("Users")
                .document(user.uid)
                .collection("Notes")
                .document("Default")
                .set(defaultData)
        }
    }
}
```

When I run above code `document.result.exist` is always `false` even when document exist.

i tried using `addOnSuccessListener` also same result.

Am i doing something wrong?

I referred many questions related to this but so solution helped.

*P.S: new to Firebase and it's APIs*

UPDATE:
If i am trying to check for any of the inner collection's and document then the result's are working fine

```
private fun createUserIfNeeded(user: FirebaseUser) {
        val notesRef = fireBaseFireStore
            .collection("Users")
            .document(user.uid)
            .collection("Notes")

        notesRef
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener {
                if (it.result == null || it.result!!.documents.size == 0) {
                    val defaultData = hashMapOf("head" to "Hello", "body" to "Welcome to NoteIt...")
                    notesRef
                        .document("Default")
                        .set(defaultData)
                }
            }
    }
```

I am not able to understand what the problem is.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  `exists()` is supposed to return false when the document doesn't exist, and true when it does exist.

Comment: Even if user(document) exist i am getting `false`. the default data code is added to the existing user  @DougStevenson

Comment: try this, Uninstall the app and reinstall

Comment: @Erik i did tried the and cleaning the app data. both didn't worked. will try it once again and get back

Comment: When developing one can by mistake view the wrong DB in Firestore console, lets say your app have a developer version and a production version, to little coffee and one might looking at wrong stuff

Comment: I am sure that is not an issue is my code logic fine?
i have uninstalling that also haven't worked

Answer (score 2):

try this, Uninstall the app and reinstall, sometimes the Firestore local cache version of you db need to be flushed, during dev

When developing one can by mistake view the wrong DB in Firestore console, lets say your app have a developer version and a production version, to little coffee and one might looking at wrong stuff